# Cartthrob Product price including vat

Tags: cartthrob

Just bought Cartthrob. But i'm having a struggle for the following.
Cartthrob automatically generates a price including vat.

So for example when I add a product with price € 10,- it will create a price € 12,10 because of my 21% vat.

But my customer wants to add product prices including Vat.
So he wants to add a product and give it the price € 10,- incl. vat.

Or else he needs te calculate all his prices to excl. vat.

Is it possible to change this way of calculating prices? So inputted prices is price incl. vat?

Thanks in advance!

Wessel

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options here.

Enter all prices incl. VAT then use the https://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/add_to_cart_form/#tax_exempt tag so VAT doesn't get added to the base price.

This is fine but assumes items are exempt from VAT and therefore doesn't account for it in reports or order details.

OR

Add prices ex VAT, but use the http://cartthrob.com/docs/fieldtypes/price_simple/#price_plus_tax tag to add your tax rate to the base price to display this on your product page.

Comment: I know this is and old answer but your second suggestion isn't practical/workable. If my product would to cost 15,95 for the end client, I would have to add the product to the system with a price of 13,181818181818182.....